# Why do the numbers still get compiled when the function value is void? C

Tags: c

I was learning about static, and I saw an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    int a = 10;
    static int sa = 10;
    a += 5;
    sa += 5;
    printf("a=%d, sa = %d\n", a, sa);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;++i)
        foo();
}
```

Here even there is void as a function, the program doesn't get an error.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: Why would it give an error? You seem to think that `void` is something that it is not.

Comment: What would the error be? `foo` is just called 10 times. Did you compile and run it?

Comment: Writing void before a function just means it doesn't return anything.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and why?

Comment: The `void` in `void foo()` is the *return type*. It's the type of the value you `return` from the function. Since you don't attempt to `return` a value you won't get an error.

Comment: A `void` function doesn't return a value to its caller; that doesn't mean it can't perform any computations or have any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In `C language` we have `void function` ,but your definition of `void function` is obviously wrong.

Like every other function `void function` can be compiled and have some number,etc in it ,but what it can't do is returning a value.

It is called `void` only because it can't return value.